# e=0. What Does That Mean for the Seasons?

Tags: hard-science, climate, orbital-mechanics, seasons

Currently, Earth's eccentricity (orbital shape) is 0.0167086.  Zero is a perfect circle whereas One is parabolic escape orbit and any greater becomes a hyperbola.  And in the theory of the Milankovitch cycles, Earth's eccentricity varies between 0.000055 and 0.0679 over a period of 100,000 years.  This affects the seasonality of planet Earth, as an extreme ellipsis can result in longer seasons.

Let us assume that Earth's eccentricity today does not exist, leaving it instead in a perfectly circular orbit.

[image]

What would a circular Earth orbit mean for the seasons and the climate?

Comment: I'm not sure why people are down voting this question. Could those with reasons for doing so state them in comments so John can improve, rather than just leaving a downvote with no indication as to why.

Comment: Of course [commenting on down votes is not required and will not be required, and there are reasons for it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250181/2389310).

Comment: Uhm, wouldn't this be better on physics.se or something?

Comment: I DV'd because this question shows no research effort. Simply googling "what if earth had a perfect orbit" resulted in me finding this passage on the second link: "Difference between farthest point i.e perihelion and nearest point I.e.aphelion is hardly 3.3%. This means that it is almost circular orbit."This difference is very mall to cause any major change. Note: Seasons on earth are due to axis of rotation and not due to elliptical orbit." In other words, a succinct answer could be found to the question within 15 seconds of me googling the actual question. I also found... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 [this link](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/seasons_orbit.php) which explains that the non-perfect orbital shape of the Earth around the sun **does not cause the seasons.**

Comment: Aify is correct the seasons are caused by axial tilt not orbital distance, which would be why summer in the northern hemisphere is winter in the southern hemisphere and vice versa.

Comment: @Aify  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles#Orbital_shape_.28eccentricity.29

Comment: @PyRulez and all other close voters: Physics will not accept this question because it is theoretical, and concerns a planet which does not exist. Physcis, Earth Science, Astronomy, etc routinely direct questions back here that are based on 'invented' worlds. This question belongs here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Eccentricity matters little (at least for Earth).**

The eccentricity of Earth (e~0.0167086) means that the planet orbits in an ellipsoidal path that is 147.1 million kilometers away from the sun at its closest and 152.1 million kilometers away at its furthest (the maximum is 3.4% larger than the minimum).  The energy output of the sun (as a blackbody radiator) is proportional to the Sun's temperature of approximately $5800K-6000K$ at the surface, which results in a power output of approximately $4.0×10^{26}\ W$.  If we want to know how much solar power hits earth we typically look at the Watts-per-square-Meter Earth recieves.  At a certain distance $r$ from the sun, the power per surface area is proportional to:
$$
P_{total}/A_{total}=P_{total}/(4\pi r^2)
$$
If you plug in the numbers for $P_{sun}$ and both $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$ you'll get the following values:
$$
1471.04\ W/m^2 \ (at \ minimum \ distance)\\
1375.92\ W/m^2 \ (at \ maximum \ distance)
$$
and notice that that is a total change of less than 7%, which doesn't seem like nearly enough difference to cause sweltering summers and freezing winters in so many different places on Earth.

Furthermore, if summer were caused by being closer to the Sun, then every continent should experience summer at the same time.  However, the Northern hemisphere experiences winter in December while the Southern hemisphere has summer in December.  So what is going on?

**Obliquity matters a lot.**

The Earth is tilted on its axis by $23.5^{\circ}$.  The axis points toward Polaris (the North Star) throughout the year, which means that during part of our orbit the Northern hemisphere will be tilted a little more toward the Sun, and during the other half of the year the Southern hemisphere will be tilted more toward the Sun.  However, we already know that distance changes don't change the $W/m^{2}$ received by much at all when we look at orbit changes, and orbital tilt is only going to change distances by a much smaller amount that eccentricity, so what is going on?

Direct sunlight is the key.  Sunlight bounces off Earth's atmosphere very similarly to how it bounces off the surface of a lake or ocean.  If you look straight down into the water very little light is reflected off the surface and you can see into the water.  But if you look out across the water a lot of sunlight is reflected and you mostly see reflections rather than seeing into the water.  This is exactly what happens to sunlight hitting the Earth's atmosphere.  In December, the tilt of the Earth places the Southern hemisphere into the most direct sunlight and very little is reflected off the atmosphere (just like very little reflects of the surface of a lake when we look straight down).  However, the Northern hemisphere is tilted away and which means the angle of the sunlight relative to the surface of the atmosphere is much less direct.  Therefore, just like more sunlight is reflected when we look out across a surface of water, more sunlight will be reflected by Earth's atmosphere when the Sunlight is less and less direct.

**What does that all mean?**

It means that fictional spacefarers or worldbuilders will have to be careful in choosing (or designing) their new Earth-like homes.

- A planet with no tilt and no eccentricity will have no seasons (barring other factors).  Such a planet will be warmest at the equator where the sunlight is most direct, and will get colder and colder as latitude increases (as more sunlight is reflected at less-direct angles).
      If the planet's sun delivers a similar $W/m^{2}$ as Earth, then the equator will be absolutely sweltering (even in comparison to Earth's).  The Arctic will be colder, never getting a warm season, and so permafrost will extend to lower latitudes than we have on Earth.  This means that the amount of land with comfortable living conditions will be centered mostly on the middle-latitude bands. (Assuming variety of landmass/oceans is similar to Earth and not some perfectly-designed masterpiece extending habitable zones by ocean currents, etc.) 
      Following similar logic a low-$W/m^{2}$ planet would push the habitable zones closer to the equator, and a high-$W/m^{2}$ planet would push the habitable zones closer to the poles.
- A planet with no tilt and high eccentricity *could* have seasons based on orbital $W/m^{2}$ fluctuations, but the orbits would have to be quite eccentric to create large temperature differences since the $W/m^{2}$ changes proportional to $(r_{max}/r_{min})^2$.
      It is also notable that Winter/Summer cycles wouldn't be very symmetric in this sort of situation.  Very eccentric orbits would lead to very short hot summers and long cold winters.
- A planet with Earth-like tilt and no eccentricity would be very Earth-like.
- A planet with Earth-like tilt and larger eccentricity *could* be very Earth-like, depending on which way the tilt is pointing.  (In other words, tilting-in at the minimal radius could make summers really scorching hot and the long cold winters colder for one hemisphere, but tilting-in during fall/spring would be pretty good.)
- Any world-building contractors can make their worlds have seasons by tailoring the tilt as they see fit.  Furthermore, why design spherical worlds when a cylinder-shape will tilt everyone to the same angle at the same angle at the same time (no more Southern/Northern hemisphere seasonal differences)

Comment: If eccentricity doesn't matter, then why did Dr. Milankovitch include it in his ice age cycle theory?

Comment: I'm not saying eccentricity doesn't matter "at all" just that obliquity is the "primary" factor effecting the seasons _as we percieve them_ on Earth.

If Earth's eccentricity were magically gone tomorrow farmers would still plant in the spring and harvest in the fall; if Earth's obliquity were magically gone tomorrow the seasons as we know them would cease.

Comment: Milankovitch's work looks at obliquity, eccentricity, and precession to account for the changing of the seasons across timescales imperceptible to those of us "living in it".  By carefully tracking all three factors Milankovitch shows how we can cycle through ice ages and warm periods over many tens of thousands of years.  Were he to have forgotten to account for eccentricity, then the other two factors wouldn't have been enough to successfully account for the entire magnitude of the temperature changes.

Comment: Changing the eccentricity of Earth will contribute to changing the period and severity of ice age cycles, but it won't effect the short-term seasonal weather or climate in the way that any settler or farmer will percieve.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

In the northern hemisphere, the winters would be a bit colder and the summers a bit hotter. In the southern hemisphere, it would be the other way around. It wouldn't be a big effect, as you can tell from the fact that seasons work pretty much the same in the northern and southern hemispheres at present despite the Earth being closer to the sun in the northern winter and southern summer.

Comment: This may be true, but it doesn’t follow the rules for a hard-science Answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Assumptions:**

- When we remove eccentricity we move to an orbit with radius of [1 AU](http://neo.jpl.nasa.gov/glossary/au.html).
- The current aphelion (maximum distance) and perihelion (minimum distance) are constants (though in fact [they can vary](http://www.indiana.edu/~geol105/images/gaia_chapter_4/milankovitch.htm)). I make this assumption because the rate of change is of the [order of thousands of years](https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/gji/11/3/10.1111/j.1365-246X.1966.tb03086.x/2/11-3-323.pdf?Expires=1488450245&Signature=R0pib2ERT7p9J3KihX1xZDYXYLLT6FBc67EkVwXmJG3P9SQw4Q9D9PGLIr6K4S74~v6KX~eoGAov6fYU22EvWvpJpuzCBPBPFCOmMrGDrqqX2SHHeyeUojWi5Qj0x2KxFcN19v7P9y8X7Rti1lPiQfDcP-7kHEEG9qjo0RT4mj3kYh1hFeQPlkMWOT80lo3VikneNn24cV5MIsgRh~Ilq106L8o-FQ5irDReyTCDn6qcbX8Yv90uhv26jfb0p0LuegCSaeASV4l8oaSaqlXyw1T9XZ-ZK10PhUD-0r-nmWFRj~b9YL9aT7M8tajAeMbi-iKgvxcHKIiNFv7EE4uMDA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIUCZBIA4LVPAVW3Q).
- Times of seasons depend only on Earth's tilt on it's axis.

**[Earth's orbital figures](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/earthfact.html):**

$r_{av}=149.60\times 10^{9}m$

$r_{pe}=147.09\times 10^{9}m$

$r_{ap}=152.10\times 10^{9}m$

**Difference in energy reaching us:**

Using the [relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law#Light_and_other_electromagnetic_radiation) that $E \propto \frac{1}{r^{2}}$ we can compare the energy change at these different points.

$$\frac{E_{av}}{E_{pe}}=\frac{r_{pe}^{2}}{r_{av}^{2}}=\frac{147.09^{2}}{149.60^{2}}=0.9667$$

$$\frac{E_{av}}{E_{ap}}=\frac{r_{ap}^{2}}{r_{av}^{2}}=\frac{152.10^{2}}{149.60^{2}}=1.0337$$

This gives us an idea of the temperature difference between the circular and elliptical orbits. The earth's core provides some of our heat so this isn't a direct relationship, we need to add a constant for the Earth's sunless-temperature.

Gathering this sunless temperature, however, is rather difficult and would involve a lot of assumptions. We have that the [power the Earth provides](http://www.solid-earth.net/1/5/2010/se-1-5-2010.pdf) is $47TW$, however this heat transfer to the surface doesn't translate easily into a temperature.

**Summary:**

- Northern hemisphere has hotter summers (increase of $\approx 1.0337$ times the amount of radiation currently), and cooler winters (decrease of $\approx 0.9667$ times the amount of radiation).
- Southern hemisphere has cooler summers (decrease of $\approx 0.9667$ times the amount of radiation currently), and warmer winters (increase of $\approx 1.0337$ times the amount of radiation).

**An explicit answer to this question would need to take into account and model the differences in cloud cover and the changes in water cycle in general**

Comment: This assumes that the only source of heat is the sun, that is that the sun is heating earth from absolute zero to where it is.

Comment: @Theraot Thank you! I knew I had done something silly somewhere. I'll make an edit to take this into account.

Comment: There are a lot of different influences. Places at the same latitude can have totally different climates.

Comment: @ths I know, I'm beginning to see that a hard-science answer requires a lot more research.

Comment: The sun is the main heat source and space is basically absolute 0.

Comment: @DonaldHobson My first answer assumed the sun was the only heat source. Following through the equations with this theory gives very large changes in temperature (in fact it flips the temperature of summer and winter for Australia with winter being warmer) and so is a clear over approximation.

Comment: Hey, your summary assumes that the eccentricity in Earth's orbit doesn't precess, i.e. that Earth is always at aphelion during NH summer. Can you add somwthing to support that?

Comment: @Spencer In my assumptions at the start I noted your point. I had the first link in already but the second refers to a paper which says the rate of this precession is of the order of thousands of years. I made the simplification that we were talking about times small compared to that - however the [paper I linked](https://academic.oup.com/gji/article-lookup/doi/10.1111/j.1365-246X.1966.tb03086.x) does talk about the precession's relationship to water temperatures throughout history (figure 1 is rather interesting if we want to talk about long term effects).